# I cannot access Django Oscar url

Tags: python, django, nginx, nginx-config, django-oscar

I deployed oscar /django application:

[image]

Whenever I try to access my site on port 8000, I get the below error page :

[image]

In my `urls.py`, I have the following:

```
from django.apps import apps
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

    # The Django admin is not officially supported; expect breakage.
    # Nonetheless, it's often useful for debugging.

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
]
```

I have no active firewalls configured and I cannot access the app URL `example.com:8000`.

In `settings.py`, I have the following configured:

```
Django settings for frobshop project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.13.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""
from oscar.defaults import *
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-z@up7l!&f*qh1%u21p*_ltv+m2^8+_9o-th+zpdih5!3ydlipd'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'oscar.config.Shop',
    'oscar.apps.analytics.apps.AnalyticsConfig',
    'oscar.apps.checkout.apps.CheckoutConfig',
    'oscar.apps.address.apps.AddressConfig',
    'oscar.apps.shipping.apps.ShippingConfig',
    'oscar.apps.catalogue.apps.CatalogueConfig',
    'oscar.apps.catalogue.reviews.apps.CatalogueReviewsConfig',
    'oscar.apps.communication.apps.CommunicationConfig',
    'oscar.apps.partner.apps.PartnerConfig',
    'oscar.apps.basket.apps.BasketConfig',
    'oscar.apps.payment.apps.PaymentConfig',
    'oscar.apps.offer.apps.OfferConfig',
    'oscar.apps.order.apps.OrderConfig',
    'oscar.apps.customer.apps.CustomerConfig',
    'oscar.apps.search.apps.SearchConfig',
    'oscar.apps.voucher.apps.VoucherConfig',
    'oscar.apps.wishlists.apps.WishlistsConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.reports.apps.ReportsDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.users.apps.UsersDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.orders.apps.OrdersDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue.apps.CatalogueDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.offers.apps.OffersDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.partners.apps.PartnersDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.pages.apps.PagesDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.ranges.apps.RangesDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.reviews.apps.ReviewsDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.vouchers.apps.VouchersDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.communications.apps.CommunicationsDashboardConfig',
    'oscar.apps.dashboard.shipping.apps.ShippingDashboardConfig',

    # 3rd-party apps that oscar depends on
    'widget_tweaks',
    'haystack',
    'treebeard',
 #  'sorl.thumbnail',   # Default thumbnail backend, can be replaced
    'django_tables2',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'oscar.apps.basket.middleware.BasketMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'frobshop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
'oscar.apps.communication.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'frobshop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oscar.apps.customer.auth_backends.EmailBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine',
    },
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
import os
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

I also tried the two below versions and did not work:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my_server_domain_or_IP', 'example.com', . . ., 'localhost']
```

The default file inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available` has the following configuration:

```
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /root/frobshop/frobshop; ## This is where settings.py exists
    }
```

But even if I delete the below lines from `settings.py`:

```
import os
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

and I delete the below lines from default file located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`:

```
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /root/frobshop/frobshop; ## This is where settings.py exists
}
```

I cannot access the app on port 8000. I actually added the above lines to make the URL accessible at example.com:8000 to no avail. How can I make the URL accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Your application should be accessible only using 127.0.0.1:8000
If you want to use other addresses then run the following command

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

If it still doesn't work then check nginx.service file for listening port number and address.
Also I recommend using gunicorn.

Comment: I run that and got `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
`